# Matrix multiplication using variable element producing Error non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, indexing, matrix-multiplication

I am a newbie to R, but avid to learn.

I have been trying endlessly to create a matrix with a variable element (in this case [2,2]). The variable element should take number 4 on the first run and 5 on the second (numbers).
This matrix would be multiplied by another matrix (N0) and produce a result matrix (resul). 
Up so far, I have only been able to create the initial matrix with the variable element using a for loop, but I am having problems indexing the result matrix. I have tried several versions, but this is the latest. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
numbers <- c(4,5,length.out = 2)
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,NA),nrow=2,ncol=2)
resul <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:2)         {
  A[2,2]<- matrix(numbers[i])
  N0 <- matrix(c(1,2),nrow=2,ncol=1)
  resul[i,]<- A[i,i]%*%N0
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two distinct problems.  the first is that `A[i,i]` is a 1 x 1
matrix, so you're getting an error because your multiplying a 1 x 1 matrix
by a 2 x 1 matrix (N0).

you could either drop the subscript `[i,i]` and initialize the result to be
a two by two matrix like so:

```
result <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=1)

for (i in 1:2){
    A[2,2]<- matrix(numbers[i])
    #  a colunm vector
    N0 <- matrix(c(1,2),
                 nrow=2,
                 ncol=1)
    # note the index is on the column b/c `A%*%N0` is a column matrix
    result[,i]<- A%*%N0
}
```

or you could either drop the the second subscript `[i,]` and initialize the result to be
a two by two matrix like so:

```
result <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=1)

for (i in 1:2){
    A[2,2]<- matrix(numbers[i])
    #  a colunm vector
    N0 <- matrix(c(1,2),
                 nrow=2,
                 ncol=1)
    result[i,]<- A[i,]%*%N0
}
```

but it's not clear from you post which (if either) answer is the correct one.  Indexing is tricky :)